I want to generate multi page pdf using node.js, express.js. i am getting the pdf content (HTML content) from text editor like CKEditor
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const renderPages = (company_letter_content, letterhead_url, markings) => {
    const { window } = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>');
    const document = window.document;
    const Node = window.Node;

    const pageHeight = 297; // A4 page height in mm
    const marginTop = parseInt(markings?.split(",")[0] || 0, 10);
    const marginBottom = parseInt(markings?.split(",")[1] || 0, 10);
    const marginLeft = parseInt(markings?.split(",")[3] || 0, 10);
    const marginRight = parseInt(markings?.split(",")[2] || 0, 10);

    const contentHeight = pageHeight - marginTop - marginBottom;

    const tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tempDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    tempDiv.style.width = "210mm";
    tempDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
    tempDiv.style.fontSize = "12px";
    tempDiv.style.lineHeight = "1.2";
    tempDiv.innerHTML = company_letter_content;

    document.body.appendChild(tempDiv);

    const pages = [];
    let currentPage = "";
    let totalHeight = 0;

    const splitContent = (node, availableHeight) => {
        const clone = node.cloneNode(true);
        tempDiv.innerHTML = "";
        tempDiv.appendChild(clone);

        let nodeHeight = tempDiv.offsetHeight / 3.77953;

        if (nodeHeight <= availableHeight) {
            return { visible: clone.outerHTML, remaining: null };
        }

        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            const content = node.textContent;
            let visibleText = "";
            let remainingText = content;

            while (remainingText.length) {
                tempDiv.textContent = visibleText + remainingText[0];
                nodeHeight = tempDiv.offsetHeight / 3.77953;
                if (nodeHeight > availableHeight) break;
                visibleText += remainingText[0];
                remainingText = remainingText.slice(1);
            }

            return { visible: visibleText, remaining: remainingText };
        }

        const children = Array.from(clone.childNodes);
        let visibleContent = "";
        let remainingContent = "";

        children.forEach((child) => {
            const { visible, remaining } = splitContent(child, availableHeight);
            if (visible) visibleContent += visible;
            if (remaining) remainingContent += remaining;
            availableHeight -= tempDiv.offsetHeight / 3.77953;
        });

        return { visible: visibleContent, remaining: remainingContent };
    };

    Array.from(tempDiv.childNodes).forEach((node) => {
        const clone = node.cloneNode(true);
        tempDiv.innerHTML = "";
        tempDiv.appendChild(clone);

        const nodeHeight = tempDiv.offsetHeight / 3.77953;
        totalHeight += nodeHeight;

        if (totalHeight <= contentHeight) {
            currentPage += node.outerHTML;
        } else {
            const { visible, remaining } = splitContent(node, contentHeight - (totalHeight - nodeHeight));

            currentPage += visible;
            pages.push(currentPage);

            currentPage = remaining || "";
            totalHeight = currentPage ? tempDiv.offsetHeight / 3.77953 : 0;
        }
    });

    if (currentPage) pages.push(currentPage);

    document.body.removeChild(tempDiv);

    return pages.map((pageContent) => ({
        pageContent,
        styles: {
            marginTop,
            marginBottom,
            marginLeft,
            marginRight,
        },
        letterhead_url,
    }));
};
 

Parameters :
  "company_letter_content":"<h2>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;OFFER LETTER</h2><p><strong>Date - 07-12-2024</strong></p><p>Dear <strong>Shashikant Jadhav,</strong></p><p>CMPEMP01</p><p>Subject:&nbsp;Offer&nbsp;Letter</p>",

 "markings":"50,25,30,30",
 "letterhead_url":"https://someurl.com"

This is the code using which i am trying to split the content in multiple pages as per content length but all the content is returning in only one page and it get overflowed.
i have tried and found that the node height is not getting calculated correctly so i have
tried using canvas, puppeteer but the issues persist.
The letter content should split on a certain page height and move to next page as per the content height, but all the content is retuned in a single page only.
Thanks in Advance.
